# Retrieve Email Id from FaceBook Login in vb.net application

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I want to integrate Facebook with my .net application which is in vb.
I want to use facebook login as open id login to my application.
I reached to login with fb and get all basic information of my facebook profile.
But still I do not get facebook login id(means facebook login email id) in my user information detail retrieved from facebook.

Please help me out to solve this.
I get first name, last name and etc. but I want email id of facebook login or primary email address.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to [prompt your users](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to grant the [`email` permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). Then you'll be able to pull the `email` field in the same API call that you get their name and basic info.

Comment: hi..thanks for reply...i get the prompt message for permission..but i want to come into next stage for retrive email id.

Comment: What do you mean by **email id**? If your users have granted the `email` permission, you should be able to get their email address by requesting the `email` field. If that's not working, please post your code that's not working.